# RESTful Web Service - resource context and response questions

Tags: java, rest, service, jaxb, response

I have developed a simple RESTful web service.

Root Resource Class:

```
@Path("/order")
@RequestScoped
public class CustOrderContainerResource {

  //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Instance Variable">
  @Context
  private UriInfo myUriInfo;

  @Context
  private ResourceContext myResourceContext;

  @Context
  private SecurityContext mySecurityContext;

  @Inject
  private CustOrderDAO myCustOrderDAO;

  public CustOrderContainerResource() {
  }


  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML})
  public List<Custorder> ReadCustomerOrder(@QueryParam("min")int min, 
      @QueryParam("max")int max, @Context Request myRequest, 
      @Context HttpHeaders myHeader) {

    int totalOrder = 0;
    List<Custorder> resultList = null;

    totalOrder = myCustOrderDAO.count();
    if(min == 0 && max == 0) {
      throw new QueryParamException("Order ID is empty");
    }
    else if(max > totalOrder) {
      throw new QueryParamException("Order ID Range is invalid");
    }
    resultList = myCustOrderDAO.findRange(min, max, "findOrderIDRange");

    return resultList;
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Custorder> ReadCustomerOrder() {

    // Check conditional get here
    return myCustOrderDAO.findAll(); 
  }

  @POST
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
  public Response createOrder(Custorder myCustOrder) {

    String orderID = null;

    myCustOrder.setStatus("pending");
    myCustOrder.setOrderdate(new Date());
    myCustOrder.setTotal("");

    // Persist
    myCustOrderDAO.create(myCustOrder);

    // Get Order ID

    // Embedded created URL for new customer order in response
    return Response.created(myUriInfo.getAbsolutePath().resolve(myCustOrder.getOrderid() + "/")).build();
  }

  @Path("{orderID}")
//  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public CustOrderResource ReadSingleCustomerOrder(@PathParam("orderID") String orderID) {

    int userOrderID = Integer.parseInt(orderID);
    int myOrderID = myCustOrderDAO.count();

    CustOrderResource myCustorder = null;

    if(userOrderID > myOrderID 
            || myCustOrderDAO.find(orderID) == null) {
      throw new OrderNotFoundException("Order ID Not Found");
    }

    if(!mySecurityContext.isUserInRole("admin")) {  
      // Propogates to specific resource class
      myCustorder = myResourceContext.getResource(CustOrderResource.class);
      myCustorder.setOrderID(orderID);
    }

    return myCustorder;
    //    return CustOrderResource.getInstance(myCustOrderDAO, orderID);
  }
}
```

Sub Resource Locator Class :

```
@RequestScoped
public class CustOrderResource {

  //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Instance Variable">
  @Inject
  private CustOrderDAO myCustOrderDAO;

  private String orderID;

  private static final Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger(CustOrderResource.class.getName()); 

  //</editor-fold>

  // ========================================================
  public CustOrderResource() {
  }

  private CustOrderResource(String orderID) {
    this.orderID = orderID;
  }


  public static Custorder getInstance(CustOrderDAO myCustOrderDAO, String orderID) {
    return myCustOrderDAO.find(orderID);
  }

  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML})
  public Custorder getCustomerOrder() {
    return myCustOrderDAO.find(orderID);
  }

  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public String updateCustomerOrder() {

    return "so";

    /*try {
      myCustOrderDAO.update(myCustOrder);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

      myLogger.log(Level.ALL, e.toString());

      throw new WebApplicationException(
              Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
              .entity("Cust Order Update Failed").build());
    }*/
  }

  @DELETE
  // 415 Unsupported media type
  public String deleteCustomerOrder() {

    return "Deleted";
    //    myCustOrderDAO.delete(myCustOrder);
  }

  public String getOrderID() {
    return orderID;
  }

  public void setOrderID(String orderID) {
    this.orderID = orderID;
  }
}
```

My question is

- AFAIK, the resource context will propagate to specific resource class
  when we specify it as an argument according to the HTTP method like
  POST or DELETE. How do I pass the parameter from sub resource locator
  method into sub resource class method?

I tried to update customer order using post method with XML data but unfortunately the JAX-RS runtime returns 415 Unsupported media type.

I am using the REST client from http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/ to test my application, by pasting an XML file into the body tab content. What is wrong with it?

- Does the JAXB automatically convert to XML when I return a list of
  objects? I have tested and it return xml format but just want
  confirmation. Is it more flexible to return response object?

I wonder how to build a response object with list of object and list of URI or Atom XML with list of object (Apache Abdera).

- How to find out a id of a newly persisted object into database in my
  `createCustomerOrder` method ?

Thanks.

Please help.

Comment: Problem solved by reading the jersey 1.7 user guide. Thanks.

Comment: Nice work peterwkc. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing object into sub resource locator class is solve by using QueryParam annotation. Newly persisted object is finding using EntityManager util.